# DateTime.ToShortDateString() orderby with linq

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose there are two products in the db.
I want to sort them by date.

The date is saved as a string in the database.

##### System.FormatException: 'String '3/23/2022' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

```
{
Name: "Product1",
Date: "23-03-2022",
}

{
Name: "Product2",
Date: "24-03-2022",
}

var orderedList = db.Product.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Date, 
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"))).ToList();
```

Comment: "The date is saved as a string in the database." - that's where things started going wrong. Fix that and many problems will not arise. When you use *appropriate* data types in the database, the database can sort the data correctly itself.

Comment: And if you absolutely *have* to use strings, use ISO-8601 format, which is naturally sortable.

Comment: As an aside, you want `en-GB` for `English (United Kingdom)`, not `gb-GB`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't want to update the database for just one list. If there is no solution, my last choice is to update the database.

Comment: @audi1m - you won't be updating the database "for just one list". You'll be preventing many future problems. For instance, does your column currently correctly reject `29-02-2021` whilst allowing `29-02-2020`?

Comment: In your example the dates are not even strings, they don't have ending quotes.

Comment: @AndrewR sorry I forgot to add quotes, I updated.

Comment: It's also confusing in terms of the error message you're showing suggesting the string format is actually "3/23/2022" when the data you've shown would format March 23rd 2022 as "23-03-2022".

Comment: And than there is the dd/mm/yyyy vs mm/dd/yyyy problem. Is 01/02/2022 the first of februari or the second of januari. All sorts of problems arise with dates in strings. I agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever, change your database.

Comment: Why would you hold a date as a string?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In the current project, the date is hold as a string. Updating as DateTime in db seems to be the only solution.

Comment: You just have a parsing problem, not a sorting problem.
I don't think x.Date has the string you think it has. 
If you try 
`DateTime.Parse("24-03-2022", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"))`
you will see it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
var orderedList = db.Product.Select(item => new {
    item,
    ymd = String.Concat(item.Date.Substring(6, 4) ,'-', item.Date.Substring(3, 2), '-', item.Date.Substring(0, 2)) /* yyyy-MM-dd format */
}).Select(x => new {
   x.item,
   datediffvalue = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("DD", "1899-12-30", x.ymd)
 }).OrderByDescending(x => x.datediffvalue ?? 0).Select(x => x.item);
```